# Laravel 5.4 External user email notification queue not being sent

Tags: laravel, email, notifications, queue, laravel-5.4

I'm using Laravel Notifications with ShouldQueue implementation to send email to external user as follows:

App\Http\Controllers\ActionController.php:

```
...
use App\Notifications\ExternalUserNotified;

class ActionController extends Controller
{
...

    public function send()
    {
        $notified_user = (new User)->forceFill([
            'name'=> 'External User',
            'email'=> 'test@email.com'
        ]);

        $notified_user->notify(new ExternalUserNotified($data));
        ...
    }
}
```

App/Notifications/ExternalUserNotified.php class:

```
...
class ExternalUserNotified extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    private $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }


    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {

        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->subject('Test Subject')
                    ->line('Dear User,')
                    ->line('Test notification content...')
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }
}
```

The queue job was successfully created and run without any error with command:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

However, there was no email sent to test@email.com (I am using MailTrap for testing). The email was successfully sent if the notification class does not implement ShouldQueue.

All conditions work if user instance is a model instance:

```
$notified_user = User::find(1);
$notified_user->notify(new ExternalUserNotified($data));
```

I suspected that the temporary new user instance:

```
$notified_user = (new User)->forceFill([
   'name'=> 'External User',
   'email'=> 'test@email.com'
]);
```

could not be recognized by the queue.

Appreciate and thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

this is how i solved the problem.

Dont use `ShouldQueue`

```
            class VerificationNewAccount extends Mailable
            {
                use Queueable, SerializesModels;
                public function __construct()
                {
                }
                public function build()
                {
                    return $this->from('noreply@example.com')
                        ->view('email.verification-request');
                }
            }
```

Instead use the basis `->queue`

```
            Mail::to('test@gmail.com')->queue(new VerificationNewAccount($ran));
```

now the email is sent to `gmail`

The weird part is that now the email is not printed in `log`. 
Well i dont care. It woks!

Laravel 5.4

Comment: Thank you @roll for the useful workaround. Do you think it is the issue of ShouldQueue or Laravel Notifications? Anyway, let me also check to see if I can implement the basic `->queue` with Notifications.